# Capturing raw video stream from second pc (HDMI Splitter & Capture Card)

Tags: ffmpeg, video, screen-capture

I would like to create a test setup in which I transmit the raw stream from one PC via an HDMI splitter and display it on a second PC where I receive the HDMI signal with a capture card..
Due to the tests, it is important to me that I transmit the stream as uncompressed or losless as possible and that it is displayed on the second PC with as little latency as possible.

As I want to adjust parameters such as frame rate, compression later on, I have thought about capturing the stream from the capture card using ffmpeg.
However, I am currently still having noticable latency on the displayed stream.

So far I tried displaying it with SDL and piping it to ffplay, where SDL produced better results in terms of delay/latency.
But in order to display it with SDL I had to change the pixel format to yuv420p because somehow SDL seemed to not be able to process the raw input.

My FFmpeg command displaying it with SDL looked something like this:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 2G -f dshow -i video="Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)" -vf format=yuv420p -f sdl -
```

It also worked with a smaller buffer size when displaying it with SDL, but since I had problems with the buffer when piping it to ffplay I increased the buffer size to 2G at some point.

When piping it to ffplay I had problems with the performance and also my buffer somehow filled up over time.
Maybe this is a hardware issue and either my CPU, RAM or disk speed is not fast enough?

I also tried using the same pixel format as above to make it better comparable:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 2G -f dshow -i video="Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)" -vf format=yuv420p -f rawvideo - | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -
```

e.g. from the command line output to show that the real time buffer is filling up over time:

```
> Input #0, rawvideo, from 'fd:':    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   =N/A
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 622080 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 622080 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (63% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 2 times  0KB vq=18225KB sq=    0B f=0/0
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (64% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 1 times  0KB vq=18225KB sq=    0B f=0/0
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (65% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 1 times  0KB vq=15187KB sq=    0B f=0/0
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (66% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (67% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 1 times  0KB vq=18225KB sq=    0B f=0/0
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (68% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 1 times  0KB vq=18225KB sq=    0B f=0/0
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (69% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
[dshow @ 000002347d9cc880] real-time buffer [Blackmagic WDM Capture (4)] [video input] too full or near too full (70% of size: 2000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
```

What I am thinking of trying out next, is to try the same on a pc with "better" Hardware to see if that improves the situation. I also thought about using losless compression instead of rawvideo, since in the end the "reference" I want to have only has to be visually losless.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how I could improve the process or other solutions that might work better.